# How can I make my Logger implementation be automatically injected by SLF4J in an application?

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, logback

So I have my own implementation of `org.slf4j.Logger` called *MyLogger*. So far so good. I have an app that uses SLF4J + LOG4J. This is configured in the pom.xml.

My question is: How do I somehow make SLF4J take my Logger implementation and inject everywhere instead of using log4j?

I am looking for an example or explanation about how to switch between SLF4J implementations (log4j, logback, MyLogger, etc) without requiring any code changes, just pom.xml configurations or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SLF4J will try inject the first compatible Logger (`org.slf4j.Logger`) it finds in the classpath. For that to happen, you log implementation must also provide a LoggerFactory through the implementation of `org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory` that returns your logger. More info here: http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#slf4j_compatible